# asp.net redirect to new window and passing value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I'm i have a gridview and a linkbutton, I want to redirect the user to another page when the linkbutton is clicked. 
but I'm passing a value when redirecting the user like this

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "cat")
    {
        Response.Redirect("coverLetter.aspx?cat=" + e.CommandArgument);
    }
}
```

This works fine but I want to redirect the user to a new window keeping the old one live
How can I do that?
 i already tried this

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('coverLetter.aspx'/,'_blank');</script>");
```

But I can't pass the value this way. 
Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the `windows.open` string with the arguments you need. E.g.:

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('coverLetter.aspx?cat=" + e.CommandArgument + "','_blank' ,'height=300,width=300');</script>")
```